# predicted accuracy of model changes with change in order of attributes in csv file using scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm inputting a large array of data with a classification of 0 or 1 into scikit-learn. However, when I change the order of the columns in my array, the cross validation accuracy of the test changes from 68% to 99%, with no change in the code. Can anyone think why this would be happening? The code is as follows:

> Blockquote

```
full_data = np.array(Datacsv)
print full_data

# Want to predict y
# first row of array is classification status 0 or 1
#
Y = full_data[:,0] 
# Image data
#
X = full_data[:, 1:]
#http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generate/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html
#provides train/test indices to split data into train/test sets (patritions into 10 random)



classification = SVC(kernel='linear',C=1)
d = classification.fit(X,Y)

scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(classification,X,Y,cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
print scores
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(),scores.std()*2))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.4,random_state=0)
kfolds = StratifiedKFold(Y,n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=None)
scores = []
sensitivity = []
specificity= []
PPV = []
NPV = []
ROC_AUC = []

for train_index, test_index in kfolds:
    Y_pred = classification.fit(X[train_index], Y[train_index]).predict(X[test_index])
    # Get accuracy score of each fold and append to scores list   
    scores.append(accuracy_score(Y[test_index], Y_pred))
    #y_prob = svm.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index]).predict_proba(X[test_index])



#make pfrom sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFoldython list to numpy array

# Generate confusion matrix from which we can get TP, FP, FN and FN
confusion = confusion_matrix(Y[test_index],Y_pred)
TP = confusion[1,1]
TN = confusion[0,0]
FP = confusion[0,1]
FN = confusion[1,0]
cv_sens = TP/ float(TP + FN) # Sensitivity
sensitivity.append(cv_sens)
cv_spec = TN / float(TN + FP) # specificity
specificity.append(cv_spec)
cv_ppv = TP / float(TP + FP) # PPV
PPV.append(cv_ppv)
cv_npv = TN / float(TN + FN)
NPV.append(cv_npv)
cv_roc_auc = roc_auc_score(Y[test_index], Y_pred)
ROC_AUC.append(cv_roc_auc)
```

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using? Seems like an older version. Please update to latest and check again.

Comment: Also, please format the code in question. It looks not correct. And where is the code which changes the order of columns?

Comment: The columns were changed manually, in the csv. file

I am doing a project on a system that is not my own, and do not have permission to update. Saying that, the system seems to think it is using 0.18.2

Comment: Either way, I have no idea why changing column order and column order alone, when they are unnamed and order doesn't matter, would change the result?

Comment: my apologies for the poorly formatted code, I'm still relatively new to both coding and Stackoverflow

Comment: How many columns do you change manually ? Which ones, among how many ? Does the result change for different changes in the columns ?

Comment: I dont think its 0.18.2. See the [documentation of StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold) of version 0.18.2. Your implementation doesnt match this.

Comment: The only column that stayed constant was the first one with the classifiers, I effectively changed the data from this pattern: 
[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 . . . k3, k4, k5]  to

Comment: [a1, b1, c1 . . . i5, j5, k5]

Comment: I see that it doesn't add up to the version, and when I change from n_folds to n_splits, the code no longer runs. I agree it sounds like I'm using a different version, but the system I am using (which I cannot update) is telling me I'm using 0.18.2. Very annoying!

Comment: Now using correct version - n_folds ammended to n_splits, no change in (or more accurately, still changing) results.

Comment: @G.Bruce  inside StratifiedKFold, set the random_state to a number and check again. From your previous comment , you mean that the results are the same finally?

Comment: @sera I added in a few random numbers just there and nothing changed

No, sorry, that wasn't very clear, the results are still changing if i change the order of the columns, which is very annoying! would uploading the data set be useful?

Comment: @G.Bruce yes if you could. I can try to run the code and see

Comment: https://spaces.hightail.com/space/USZwOtluEL -- File should be in there. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: The code snippet should run if the directories and indentation are there (I have since fixed the indentation in my own code) 

The only other changes are n_folds now needs to be n_splits and the Y in stratifiedKfold has been removed

Comment: Also, background wise, I have 36 parameters being used to describe whether or not someone is normal (0) or abnormal (1). The parameters have been ranked on a 1-6 scale, which is why all the numbers are in that range

Comment: I'm still sitting with the same problem =S I get 99% accuracy on a variety of orders I've tried